# bash arrays of strings

Tags: arrays, bash, hash

I have an elaborate script that must use different code bits depending on where it's ran.

There is no good way for this to be dynamically determined, instead it must hardcoded in and looked up at the time of execution.

What I think I need is something like this

```
{
 "location": {
   "type1": [ "hostname1", "hostname2", "hostname 3" ],
   "type2": [ "hostname4, "hostname5", "hostname6"],
   "type3": [ "hostname7, "hostname8", "hostname9"]
  }
}

case $array[$(hostname)] in #pseudocode 
  type1) bash $dir/type1.sh;;
  type2) bash $dir/type2.sh;;
  *) bash $dir/type3.sh;;
esac
```

Then I can somehow query to find the key whose value contains the value of the script executor's hostname

In ruby this would be as simple as creating a hash and looking up the value. 
Is this possible in bash?

```
hash.key(Socket.gethostname)
```

Comment: Waitaminute. Are you doing a lookup by host, or by type? Your pseudocode says the former, but your dictionary is created for the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's going to be hard-coded into the script anyway, consider simply using `case`:

```
case $(hostname) in
  (hostname1|hostname2|hostname3) bash "$dir/type1.sh";;
  (hostname4|hostname5|hostname6) bash "$dir/type2.sh";;
  (*) bash "$dir/type3.sh";;
esac
```

Comment: You know what this is smarter and much easier. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If you fix the quoting, you will have a good solution as pointed out in the comments below the other answer.

Comment: Repaired the quoting and spacing/indentation; thanks to David and Charles for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

You can store arrays of strings in bash, and you can store maps in bash, but you can't store arrays as the values in maps.

However, if your type names only use characters that are valid in shell variable names, you can cheat by storing each array in a separate variable, and using indirect references to look up or iterate over the variable names.

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $BASH_VERSION ]] && ! [[ $BASH_VERSION =~ ^([0123][.]|4[.][012]) ]] || {
  echo "This requires bash 4.3 or later" >&2
  exit 1
}

# we're declaring any variable name starting with loc_ to be part of our data
loc_type1=( "hostname1" "hostname2" "hostname3" )
loc_type2=( "hostname4" "hostname5" "hostname6" )
loc_type3=( etc etc etc )

# map from type to hostnames; "hosts_for_type type1" will emit hostnames 1-3
hosts_for_type() {
  local -n type_arr="loc_$1"
  printf '%s\n' "${type_arr[@]}"
}

# do the heavy lifting to build a map from hostnames to types
# this only needs to be run once for the given data
declare -g -A type_for_host=( )
build_hosttype_map() {
  local varname typename host

  # abort if inverse map is already built so this only runs once
  (( ${#type_for_host[@]} )) && return

  for varname in "${!loc_@}"; do
    declare -n locarr="$varname"
    typename=${varname#loc_}
    for host in "${locarr[@]}"; do
      type_for_host[$host]=$typename
    done
  done
}

# map from hostname to type; uses inverse map built above.
type_for_host() {
  build_hosttype_map
  printf '%s\n' "${type_for_host[$1]}"
}
```

With the above defined:

```
$ type_for_host hostname1
type1
$ hosts_for_type type1
hostname1
hostname2
hostname3
```

(If you want to handle data elements containing all possible characters, you'll want to switch from newline delimiters to NULs, by changing the `'%s\n'` format strings to `'%s\0'`; however, inasmuch as our input domain is presently composed only of valid hostnames, that's not immediately called for).

Comment: Oh my that is uglier than I expected even bash to be. I really appreciate the effort that went into this.

Comment: Heh. There's a big difference between syntactical ugliness and conceptual ugliness -- there's a lot of syntax here, but it's well-defined syntax that's going to behave in consistent ways regardless of runtime environment, data, etc (other than carving out our reserved variable namespace with the `loc_` prefix, of course). That's as compared to things like `for file in $(find ...)` that don't *look* awful, but are actually full of corner cases and ugliness in terms of what they do at runtime.

Comment: Even the accepted answer, short as it is, has some places where it has the other, subtler (and I'd argue more serious) kind of ugliness: `$dir/type1.sh` is going to behave in unexpected ways if your directory name has spaces in it or your `IFS` value contains a character in that name (such as `/`); it needs to be `"$dir"/type1.sh` (or `"$dir/type1.sh"`) to be correct without preconditions or caveats.

Comment: Some just prefer the comic section instead of Shakespeare... Although with the quoting corrections, it is pretty short and to the point...

Comment: Definitely -- the other (as corrected) *should* be the accepted answer; it's much more appropriate to the OP's immediate use case than this is. (This answer has value if someone's going to need to dynamically build that map and then do an arbitrary number of reverse lookups efficiently, so I think it adds something of value to the question, but it's not the best choice for the OP right now).